# expected value word problem (game chances)

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

**In a certain game, a player pays $5 to roll a single die, and is paid ( − )^2 dollars if the die showed  on top. What is the expected value, rounded to the nearest whole number of cents, of the person’s profit when they play this game once?**

I am struggling to understand this problem. I am unsure of when to use various formulas for expected value/profit to solve it.

*Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $k$ be $\sum_{m=1}^n (m-2)^2$, the sum of all possible prizes for a die with n sides. It's easy to see that $\frac{k}{n}$ is the average amount we will win with every throw. Finally, and accounting for the entry price (i.e. 5), we get:

$$
q(n) = (\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{(m-2)^2}{n}) - 5
$$

representing the profit for every throw.

If we have a die with 6 sides, for instance, the profit for every throw will be: $q(6) = 1/6$.

Comment: Please review carefully the current policy of [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which now applies to not only askers, but also the answerers that answer very low quality questions